# Django filter object for multiple args

Tags: python, django, object

The issue currently is filtering for all users that

1. Are not the user
2. Where model field == True

If I remove the ".filter(model="True")" than the first requirement is met. How can I add more filters to the users?

Current error message:

> FieldError at /explore/ Cannot resolve keyword 'model' into field.
>   Choices are: date_joined, email, emailaddress, favorite, first_name,
>   groups, id, images, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login,
>   last_name, logentry, owner, password, profile, socialaccount,
>   user_permissions, username, webhook

I understand that the error means. However, I'm not sure how to implement it in the code.

view.py

```
def explore(request, pk=None):
    template_name = 've/cp/explore.html'

    users_list = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).filter(model="True")

    paginator = Paginator(users_list, 16)  # Show x per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    users = paginator.get_page(page)

    try:
        favorite = Favorite.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        favorites = favorite.users.all()
    except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
        favorites = None

    args = {
        'favorites': favorites, 'users': users,
    }

    return render(request, template_name, args)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__` with profile keyword:

```
users_list = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).filter(profile__model="True")
```

Comment: Are you my guardian angel? This worked perfectly.. I'm a bit disappointed I did not realize that. If I need to add more filters could I keep adding .filter()

Comment: @AlexWinkler you can just pass additional args to single filter: `filter(profile__model="True", email="abc@abc.com")`. This will filter records wich fit both conditions.

Comment: @AlexWinkler check this section of doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: @AlexWinkler If you wondering about `profile..` in the answer it is related name that django automtically generates for the reverse relationship.(ie, `User` model to the `Profile`)